# Update and Save Value on ng-Click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a multi-page-form using an ui-router. During the first part of the form, the user will select a button. This button's value will be used to sort the table that is loaded on the second page. I thought I could set/update the buttons value with the ng-click, but it is not saving. The second page doesn't sort by the updated value.

My specific problem is in my firstPage.html - when my ng-button is clicked. The original value of sortType is: `sortType = ''`. My plan was to set my sortType value on this page. This is how I did it:

```
<a ui-sref="orderForm.step2" 
   ng-click="sortType ='name'" 
   class="btn btn-block btn-info">
```

I thought that `ng-click="sortType ='name'"` would have updated and saved the sortType value. However, when the second page is still: `sortType= ''`. Do any of you have suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Here's my firstPage.html:

```
<div class="form-group row" ng-controller="formController">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <a ui-sref="orderForm.step2" 
           ng-click="sortType ='name'" 
           class="btn btn-block btn-info">
           Title 
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <h1>Presorted</h1> 
    <pre>{{sortType}}</pre>
</div>
```

Here's my second page:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="formController">
    <h2> Sort type: </h2>
    <pre>{{sortType}}</pre>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Beverage</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Type</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Popularity</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="drink in drinks | orderBy: sortType | filter:searchDrink">
            <td>{{drink.name}}</td>
            <td>{{drink.type}}</td>
            <td>{{drink.popularity}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here's my App.js Page:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('orderForm', {
            url: '/orderForm',
            templateUrl: 'orderForm.html',
            controller: 'formController'
         })

        .state('orderForm.step1', {
            url: '/step1',
            templateUrl: 'step1.html'
         })

         .state('orderForm.step2', {
            url: '/step2',
            templateUrl: 'step2.html'
         });

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/orderForm/step1');
 })

.controller('formController', function($scope) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.processForm = function() {
         alert('Thank you!');
     };

     $scope.sortType     = ''; 
     $scope.sortReverse  = false;  
     $scope.searchDrink    = '';     

     //Lists of Drinks:
     $scope.drinks = [
        {name:'Americano', type: 'Espresso Beverage', popularity: 4},
        {name:'Raspberry Tea', type: 'Tea', popularity: 2},
        {name:'Vanilla Latte', type: 'Espresso Beverage', popularity: 3 },
        {name:'Mocha', type: 'Espresso Beverage', popularity: 8},
        {name:'Pike', type: 'Freshly Brewed Coffee', popularity: 6},
        {name:'Green Tea', type: 'Tea', popularity: 4},
        {name:'Frappuccino', type: 'Iced Drinks', popularity: 5},
        {name:'Fruit Smoothie', type: 'Iced Drinks', popularity: 6}
    ];

});
```

Comment: you could make a function in controller that is called by click eg `ng-click="changeSortType('name')"`

Comment: Hi Dinesh - would that look something like this: 
    $scope.changeSortType = function(n) {
        $scope.sortType = n; 
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you route using UiRouter, it initializes your controller each time it is called, in this case, between pages.

What you need here is a service that will hold your values, as it is only instantiated once (a singleton).

further reading: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXpHV5gWgyk

Comment: Okay, I added a factory service to my code: `.factory('Data', function() {
    var sortType = ''; 
    return sortType; 
})`  I deleted the sortType that I had declared in my 'formController' controller. It updates on the first page, but on the second page, it didn't save the change. Both my first page and second page use 'formController' - do they need to be using separate names?

Comment: you are going to want to return an object from your service, and write changes to that object as Data.sortType. `.factory('Data', function() { return {sortType: '' })` Make sure to update your bindings to point to Data.sortType too!

Comment: Hi @lucky7id - Thanks for your help, unfortunately it's still is not saving. My factory looks like this: `.factory('Data', function() {   return { sortType: ''}; })` My firstPage.html button contains: `ng-click="Data.sortType ='name'"`; I check the value in my second page with: `<pre>{{Data.sortType}}</pre> `  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In order for that to work, you would need to make Data available on your controller $scope such as `$scope.Data = Data`. Be sure that you have injected your Data service in the controller as well

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for all your help @lucky7id! I appreciate your explanations. I'm new to  Angular JS, so I'm still learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a page is loaded, the controller is instantiated. And because you have `$scope.sortType = '';` at the top of your controller, the value is set to ''.

Also, in your template, by doing `sortType = 'name'` you're binding the value to the variable `sortType` of your controller's $scope. But each controller has it's own scope. So you won't be able to pass the variable like that.

The quick and dirty way would be to bind the value to the $rootScope.
Then in your second controller you could do `$rootScope.sortType`.

My advice would actually be to use something like angular-wizard since this is what you seem to want to achieve: https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard

Comment: Thanks MonsieurNinja. I'll look into that link. When you say "$rootScope" is the quick/dirty way... does that mean it's sort of a hack and not recommended?

Comment: You should avoid $rootScope as much as possible, for the same reason you should avoid polluting your global namespace. It's generally a bad practice, and there are much cleaner ways to achieve your goals.